# Expected value in a poisson distribution when there's a maximum possible value

Tags: statistics

Bit confused with a certain part of this q:
A shop has four copies of the magazine B delivered each week. The demand follows a Poisson distribution with mean 3.2 requests per week.
Find the expected number of books sold each week.

So the answer is 2.8, but I'm not sure what you're supposed to do with a Poisson distribution that has a maximum possible value. I tried to work out the mean using the poisson E(x) formula but going up to 4 not infinity, but then I got 1.928. When I did the sum up to 5 I got 2.5 which was a bit closer to the answer but I was just guessing, I'm just not sure what the method is or how you're supposed to approach it.

Comment: Can you show how you calculate the $\mathbb{E}[X]$ formula?

Comment: @Victor Glombik sorry I don't have enough reputation points to add a pic. And I'm not too sure how to use latex or how you're using symbols... The equation I used was basically sum (from 0 to 4) of xe^-3.2(3.2)^x / x! which gave me 1.798, and sum from 0 to 5 gave me 2.5 which was a bit closer to the answer

Comment: @Viktor Glombik Thanks! I used this formula: $\sum_{x=0}^4 \frac{xe^{-3.2}3.2^x}{x!}$

Answer (score 1):

Your $\sum\limits_{x=0}^4 \dfrac{xe^{-3.2}3.2^x}{x!} \approx 1.928$ deals with what happens when demand is $4$ or fewer

but you need to add to this what happens when demand is $5$ or more.  In that situation $4$ are sold so you need to add $\sum\limits_{x=5}^\infty \dfrac{4e^{-3.2}3.2^x}{x!}$. That infinite sum is a little annoying, but  is $= 4-\sum\limits_{x=0}^4 \dfrac{4e^{-3.2}3.2^x}{x!} \approx 0.878$

Adding these two together gives about $2.806$

Comment: Nice thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is an unspoken assumption that you're supposed to find mean number of books sold *at equilibrium*. This is essentially a a queue with arrival process with constant rate $4$ per day and service process described by this Poisson probabilities.

You can imagine states of the shops storage as non-negative integers and transitions between them form a Markov chain. If we order them from left to right from zero to infinity we get that transitions to the right occur in steps of 4 this should give you a recurrence relation for equilibrium distribution of the number of books in the store, from that you can compute the number of books sold.

This sound like quite a laborious approach.

Alternatively this can be described as a G/M/1 queue which sells books continuously at rate 3.2/week with exponential waiting times and books arrive at constant intervals. It seems that there should be some clever trick in queueing theory to finish this off from there...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think the question is a little simpler than how you're approaching it. Since they're magazines I think you assume that any unsold magazines will be discarded weekly, as they're out of date, so none are queued for the next week. The question you're answering sounds both very interesting and insanely difficult aha no clue how I'd approach that!

Comment: @aralk Oh, that makes more sense with *magazines*. It turns out linguistics is where I've failed.